# SQL Server 2012, erro ao executar consulta

Tags: sql-server, query

Boa tarde, pessoal

ao executar a consulta abaixo:

```
select PRO_Descricao, PED_Numero
from pedido p, item i, produto pr
where p.PED_Numero = i.PED_Numero
and i.PRO_Codigo = pr.PRO_Codigo
and PRO_Descricao >= 'SA'
and pro_descricao < 'SB'
```

aparece a seguinte mensagem no SQL server 2012:

```
Nome da coluna 'PED_Numero' ambíguo.
```

O que há de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PED_Numero` é uma coluna que existe em `pedido` e em `item`.

Para desfazer a ambiguidade, defina identificadores de tabela para as colunas e para as tabelas envolvidas:

```
select pr.PRO_Descricao, p.PED_Numero
from pedido p, item i, produto pr
where p.PED_Numero = i.PED_Numero
and i.PRO_Codigo = pr.PRO_Codigo
and pr.PRO_Descricao >= 'SA'
and pr.pro_descricao < 'SB'
```

Comment: Agradeço amigo, deu certo aqui.